# How to Sort DataTable.Select() randomly

Tags: c#, datatable

How can I do that using Select()?

If translated in SQL, it will be like this:

```
select * from sometable where (somecondition) order by somefieldname desc, newid()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var rand = new Random();    
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => rand.Next());
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it. Sorting on NEWID() in T-SQL to return rows in random order is a hack, albeit a useful one. There's no equivalent hack for DataTable.Select().

Comment: @Gerald `r` is a `row` in the DataTable (which we in the case dont need for the sorting)

Comment: FYI - I attempted to use this method and found that the OrderBy was losing records after sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Randomizing rows in a DataTable:

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2008/04/16/50729.aspx

Also, from the comments:

"Did you consider just assing a GUID to the rndSortId column and Sorting on that column?

Because GUIDs are random you should get a fast, simple, and random sort."

Comment: so I can't use the sort of the Select() method?

Comment: I don't think so, you have to sort *on* something, either a table name or an expression, as defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.71).aspx. There doesn't seem to be a way to create random values as you do in your T-SQL example.